# How to automate preservation of data so it doesn’t "roll off"

Tags: excel, automation, power-automate

I have two data sets and they both have the same column names. One of the data sets is an excel file and contains historical data up until April. The second data set is linked to a database but will only ever contain 6 rolling months' worth of data. I am appending the two datasets and removing duplicates in PowerBI Power Query. I'd like to prioritise the data from the live source, but also ensure that the data doesn't get lost.Eg. what will happen to May data in 14 months from now, since it is not in the current excel data set, and it will not be in the live data set? I'd like to ensure that May data doesn't disappear in 14 months' time?

How do I automate preservation of data in Excel file so it doesn’t "roll off"